# NetworkExtension - NEVPNManager

Tags: objective-c, frameworks, vpn, ios8

Apple published with iOS 8 a new Framework "NetworkExtension".

I want to start a VPN Connection out of an app with the NEVPNManager, or has this Framework another use?

Has somebody information or an example about this Framework?
I can´t find information about it on the developer.apple.com website, only in the header files.

Thanks

Comment: there's another question on this apparently new framework here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24970280/connect-to-vpn-programmatically-in-ios-8

Comment: Maybe my answer could help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29018868/ios-cannot-set-vpn-programmatically/36124092#36124092

Answer (score 8):

The code would look something like this (exact implementation depends on the type of VPN):

```
NEVPNManager *manager = [NEVPNManager sharedManager];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(vpnConnectionStatusChanged) name:NEVPNStatusDidChangeNotification object:nil];

NEVPNProtocolIPSec *protocol = [[NEVPNProtocolIPSec alloc] init];
protocol.username = @“[Your username]”;
protocol.passwordReference = [KeyChainAccess loadDataForServiceNamed:@“[Your Service Name]"];
protocol.serverAddress = @“[Your Server Address]“;
protocol.authenticationMethod = NEVPNIKEAuthenticationMethodCertificate;
protocol.localIdentifier = @“[Your Local identifier]”;
protocol.remoteIdentifier = @“[Your Remote identifier]”;
protocol.useExtendedAuthentication = NO;
protocol.identityData = [Your VPN certification private key];
protocol.disconnectOnSleep = NO;
[manager setProtocol:protocol];

[manager setOnDemandEnabled:NO];
[manager setLocalizedDescription:@"VPN"];
NSArray *array = [NSArray new];
[manager setOnDemandRules: array];
NSLog(@"Connection desciption: %@", manager.localizedDescription);
NSLog(@"VPN status:  %i", manager.connection.status);

[manager loadFromPreferencesWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
    // do config stuff
    [manager saveToPreferencesWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
    }];
}];


NSError *startError;
[[NEVPNManager sharedManager].connection startVPNTunnelAndReturnError:&startError];
if(startError) {
      NSLog(@"Start error: %@", startError.localizedDescription);
}
```

Comment: Are you able to use this if you are not a MDM vendor?

Comment: @Array Yes, you don't need any preliminary approval from Apple, you just have to pass standard app approval process as always.

Comment: How would you pass the certification private key data? Is the cert added to the app like in the bundle? if we don't set the identityData would we be prompted for password everytime we connect to the vpn?