# Connect to VPN programmatically in iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, vpn

Since the release of iOS 8 beta, I found a Network Extension framework in its bundle which is going to let developers configure and connect to VPN servers programmatically and without any profile installation.

The framework contains a major class called NEVPNManager. This class also has 3 main methods that let me save, load or remove VPN preferences. I’ve written a piece of code in viewDidLoad method as following:

```
NEVPNManager *manager = [NEVPNManager sharedManager];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(vpnConnectionStatusChanged) name:NEVPNStatusDidChangeNotification object:nil];
[manager loadFromPreferencesWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
    if(error) {
        NSLog(@"Load error: %@", error);
    }}];
NEVPNProtocolIPSec *p = [[NEVPNProtocolIPSec alloc] init];
p.username = @“[My username]”;
p.passwordReference = [KeyChainAccess loadDataForServiceNamed:@"VIT"];
p.serverAddress = @“[My Server Address]“;
p.authenticationMethod = NEVPNIKEAuthenticationMethodCertificate;
p.localIdentifier = @“[My Local identifier]”;
p.remoteIdentifier = @“[My Remote identifier]”;
p.useExtendedAuthentication = NO;
p.identityData = [My VPN certification private key];
p.disconnectOnSleep = NO;
[manager setProtocol:p];
[manager setOnDemandEnabled:NO];
[manager setLocalizedDescription:@"VIT VPN"];
NSArray *array = [NSArray new];
[manager setOnDemandRules: array];
NSLog(@"Connection desciption: %@", manager.localizedDescription);
NSLog(@"VPN status:  %i", manager.connection.status);
[manager saveToPreferencesWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
   if(error) {
      NSLog(@"Save error: %@", error);
   }
}];
```

I also placed a button in my view and set its TouchUpInside action to the method below:

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender {
   NSError *startError;
   [[NEVPNManager sharedManager].connection startVPNTunnelAndReturnError:&startError];
   if(startError) {
      NSLog(@"Start error: %@", startError.localizedDescription);
   }
}
```

There are two problems here:

1) When I try to save the preferences, the following error will be thrown:  Save error: Error Domain=NEVPNErrorDomain Code=4 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NEVPNErrorDomain error 4.)” What is this error? How can I solve this issue?

2) [[NEVPNManager sharedManager].connection startVPNTunnelAndReturnError:&startError]; method doesn’t return any error when I call it but the connection status changes from Disconnected to Connecting for just a moment and then it gets back to Disconnected state.

Any help will be appreciated :)

Comment: weird, when I am running a copy of your code on a device with beta 4 I'm getting a nil returned from [NEVPNManager sharedManager];

Comment: Ah, I had not added the "Personal VPN" entitlement to my App ID or entitlements file. To do so, go to "Capabilities" under the project

Comment: How are you retrieving the password from the keychain? I've stored the password for my account in the keychain, and I have tried retrieving the persistent reference (which the docs imply are necessary) into the protocol.passwordReference field but it still prompts me for a password when I go to connect to the VPN service (once I enter it, I connect, so everything else seems good).

Comment: Use of the ```NEVPNManager``` class requires the ```com.apple.developer.networking.vpn.api``` entitlement. You can get this entitlement for your app by enabling the "Personal VPN" capability for your app in Xcode.

Comment: why not connect free vpn ip address  objective c

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The problem is the error you are getting when saving:
`Save error: Error Domain=NEVPNErrorDomain Code=4`

If you look in the NEVPNManager.h header file, you will see that error code 4 is "NEVPNErrorConfigurationStale". The configuration is stale and needs to be loaded. 
You should call `loadFromPreferencesWithCompletionHandler:` and *in the completion handler* modify the values you want to modify, and *then* call `saveToPreferencesWithCompletionHandler:`. The example in your question is modifying the configuration before the loading is completed, which is why you are getting this error.

More like this:

```
[manager loadFromPreferencesWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
     // do config stuff
     [manager saveToPreferencesWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
     }];
}];
```

Comment: It works OK! One more thing is that, this functionality works only and real devices not simulator.

Comment: By the way: I'll blog about this tonight and I'll mention you man ;)

Comment: Have you tried this on beta5? I have similar code that works up to beta 4, and on beta 5 I got an error: Domain=NEConfigurationErrorDomain Code=2 "Missing name" UserInfo=0x170078940 {NSLocalizedDescription=Missing name}

Comment: Do you have any idea about the "Missing name" error?

Comment: same Missing Name error in xcode 6-beta 6 ! Any solution?

Comment: The missing name issue showed up to me, when I actually forgot to set a username.

Comment: I get a 'Missing identity' error when trying to save the config in preferences. Any solution? (working with iOS 8.2)

Comment: When you use the authentication mode Certificate it needs this certificate set in the protocol as an NSData object `prot.authenticationMethod = NEVPNIKEAuthenticationMethod.Certificate; prot.identityData = certificate; prot.identityDataPassword = self._PKCS12CertificatePassword` (swift code)

Comment: @quellish then if i did as you said in your answer now getting this error : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47550706/error-domain-nevpnerrordomain-code-1-null-while-connecting-vpn-server can you please help me ?

Answer (score 10):

This answer will be helpful for those who are looking for solution using Network Extension framework.

My requirement was to connect/disconnect VPN server with IKEv2 Protocol (of course you can use this solution for IPSec also by changing vpnManager protocolConfiguration)

NOTE : If you are looking for L2TP Protocol, Using Network extension its not possible to connect VPN server. Refer : https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/29909

Here is my working code snippet :

Declare VPNManager Object and other useful things

```
var vpnManager = NEVPNManager.shared()
var isConnected = false

@IBOutlet weak var switchConntectionStatus: UISwitch!    
@IBOutlet weak var labelConntectionStatus: UILabel!
```

Add observer in viewDidLoad for getting VPN Staus and store vpnPassword in Keychain, you can store sharedSecret too which will you need IPSec protocol.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    let keychain = KeychainSwift()
    keychain.set("*****", forKey: "vpnPassword")

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.VPNStatusDidChange(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name.NEVPNStatusDidChange, object: nil)

 }
```

Now in my app was having UISwitch to connect/disconnect VPN server.

```
func switchClicked() {

    switchConntectionStatus.isOn = false

    if !isConnected {
        initVPNTunnelProviderManager()
    }
    else{
        vpnManager.removeFromPreferences(completionHandler: { (error) in

            if((error) != nil) {
                print("VPN Remove Preferences error: 1")
            }
            else {
                self.vpnManager.connection.stopVPNTunnel()
                self.labelConntectionStatus.text = "Disconnected"
                self.switchConntectionStatus.isOn = false
                self.isConnected = false
            }
        })
    }
}
```

After clicking on switch initiate VPN tunnel using below code.

```
func initVPNTunnelProviderManager(){

    self.vpnManager.loadFromPreferences { (error) -> Void in

        if((error) != nil) {
            print("VPN Preferences error: 1")
        }
        else {

            let p = NEVPNProtocolIKEv2()
// You can change Protocol and credentials as per your protocol i.e IPSec or IKEv2

            p.username = "*****"
            p.remoteIdentifier = "*****"
            p.serverAddress = "*****"

            let keychain = KeychainSwift()
            let data = keychain.getData("vpnPassword")

            p.passwordReference = data
            p.authenticationMethod = NEVPNIKEAuthenticationMethod.none

//          p.sharedSecretReference = KeychainAccess.getData("sharedSecret")! 
// Useful for when you have IPSec Protocol

            p.useExtendedAuthentication = true
            p.disconnectOnSleep = false

            self.vpnManager.protocolConfiguration = p
            self.vpnManager.isEnabled = true

            self.vpnManager.saveToPreferences(completionHandler: { (error) -> Void in
                if((error) != nil) {
                    print("VPN Preferences error: 2")
                }
                else {


                    self.vpnManager.loadFromPreferences(completionHandler: { (error) in

                        if((error) != nil) {

                            print("VPN Preferences error: 2")
                        }
                        else {

                            var startError: NSError?

                            do {
                                try self.vpnManager.connection.startVPNTunnel()
                            }
                            catch let error as NSError {
                                startError = error
                                print(startError)
                            }
                            catch {
                                print("Fatal Error")
                                fatalError()
                            }
                            if((startError) != nil) {
                                print("VPN Preferences error: 3")
                                let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Oops..", message:
                                    "Something went wrong while connecting to the VPN. Please try again.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
                                alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default,handler: nil))

                                self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                                print(startError)
                            }
                            else {
                                self.VPNStatusDidChange(nil)
                                print("VPN started successfully..")
                            }

                        }

                    })

                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Once VPN started successfully you can change the status accordingly i.e. by calling VPNStatusDidChange

```
func VPNStatusDidChange(_ notification: Notification?) {

    print("VPN Status changed:")
    let status = self.vpnManager.connection.status
    switch status {
    case .connecting:
        print("Connecting...")
        self.labelConntectionStatus.text = "Connecting..."
        self.switchConntectionStatus.isOn = false
        self.isConnected = false

        break
    case .connected:
        print("Connected")
        self.labelConntectionStatus.text = "Connected"
        self.switchConntectionStatus.isOn = true
        self.isConnected = true
        break
    case .disconnecting:
        print("Disconnecting...")
        self.labelConntectionStatus.text = "Disconnecting..."
        self.switchConntectionStatus.isOn = false
        self.isConnected = false

        break
    case .disconnected:
        print("Disconnected")
        self.labelConntectionStatus.text = "Disconnected..."
        self.switchConntectionStatus.isOn = false
        self.isConnected = false

        break
    case .invalid:
        print("Invalid")
        self.labelConntectionStatus.text = "Invalid Connection"
        self.switchConntectionStatus.isOn = false
        self.isConnected = false

        break
    case .reasserting:
        print("Reasserting...")
        self.labelConntectionStatus.text = "Reasserting Connection"
        self.switchConntectionStatus.isOn = false
        self.isConnected = false

        break
    }
}
```

I've referred from here :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/47569982/3931796

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/25928

http://blog.moatazthenervous.com/create-a-vpn-connection-with-apple-swift/

Thank you :)

Comment: i have followed your steps , but i am getting "Unexpected Error" alert while connecting to vpn, my ikev2 server uses .crt and i already have it installed on my device , manually added configuration works good , only personal vpn with same configuration getting error

Comment: Installed .crt can work with both added configuration and Personal vpn ? or we have to do something else for Personal vpn to use certificate?

Comment: KeychainSwift not works here it just return the String as Data you need a keychain ref http://blog.moatazthenervous.com/create-a-key-chain-for-apples-vpn/

Comment: @KooroshGhorbani i am facing the same issue used this class it is getting crashed while saving preferences .

Answer (score 0):

I tested other solutions multiple times and noticed that

### Putting `saveToPreferences` in `loadFromPreferences` is NOT Enough!!

Consider we already loaded a manager instance (or created new without loading), calling save inside of completion-handler of load was for me working randomly (sometimes), and having my ages of debugging experience, it seemed like `iOS` just needed time (to process something?!).

So queueing for later always works instead of randomly, like:

```swift
guard let manager = self.manager else { return }

manager.loadFromPreferences(completionHandler: { _ in
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) {
        // Change some settings.
        manager.isEnabled = true
        // Save changes directly (without another load).
        manager.saveToPreferences(completionHandler: {
            [weak self] (error) in
            if let error = error {
                manager.isEnabled = false;
                print("Failed to enable - \(error)")
                return
            }
            // Establishing tunnel really needs reload.
            manager.loadFromPreferences(completionHandler: { [weak self] (error) in
                if let error = error {
                    print("Failed to reload - \(error)")
                    return
                }
                let session = (manager.connection as! NETunnelProviderSession);
                session.startVPNTunnel()
            });
        });
    }
});
```

> **Note** that I put loading around above's main-thread, but just to be sure, and loading is ONLY required if you don't have an instance already (or if it was changed).