# Download and Install VPN profile in an IOS device from the server

Tags: ios, ios8, vpn

I need to create an IOS 8 application like HMA! pro VPN app to download a vpn profile which is stored on the server as a configuration file and install it on the device when the application first launches and it should also connect to VPN on button click

Comment: You will have to open the link in safari (in your code), and after the user installs, the user can then open the app back up.

Answer (score 0):

Follow link step by step...

[Connect to VPN programmatically in iOS 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24970280/connect-to-vpn-programmatically-in-ios-8)

http://ramezanpour.net/post/2014/08/03/configure-and-manage-vpn-connections-programmatically-in-ios-8/

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/iPhoneOTAConfiguration/profile-service/profile-service.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009505-CH2-SW37

Comment: Thanx Rahul I will look into this code and will let you know