# Redirect user using NetworkExtension framework

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios9, networkextension

I have an application that uses [NEFilterProvider API](https://developer.apple.com/reference/networkextension/nefilterprovider) to filter urls (allows/blocks browsing). ControlProvider and DataProvider extensions created.

So for this point I can block/allow certain urls.
I wonder if there is a way to implement redirection to custom url using NetworkExtension ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [NEFilterDataProvider](https://developer.apple.com/reference/networkextension/nefilterdataprovider):

> If the Filter Data Provider chooses to block the web page, then a special “block” page is displayed in the WebKit browser object informing the user that their attempt to access the content was blocked. The Filter Data Provider can choose to add a link to this block page, giving the user the option of requesting access to the content.

There is no other way to redirect user besides a link from "block" page. Neither url nor page content could be changed using NEFilterProvider API.

The best solution for redirection would be a VPN connection. You can find example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24970280/connect-to-vpn-programmatically-in-ios-8).