# NEVPNManager connect to VPN only inside in application

Tags: ios, vpn, nevpnmanager

I create application vpn [with this toturial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24970280/connect-to-vpn-programmatically-in-ios-8).but my problem is user can go to setting iPhone and connect to vpn.but I want user ONLY go to my application and connect to VPN.

My question is what should I in code `NEVPNManager`until the user can't turn on my VPN in setting iPhone and Only connecting to my VPN when user go to my application

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not possible by the API, but if you want a dirty solution, you can add a prefix to the username / password, so when the user tries to connect to your VPN via the Settings app, he would get username/password error.
And when the user would press connect at your app, you will discard the prefix so he would be able to connect.