# Send all traffic over VPN connection Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am creating an application to connect to a VPN server.  I have worked out how to do this, but need to be able to send all traffic over the connection.  Is there any code which can do this?  So far I have tried:

```
let manager: NEVPNManager = NEVPNManager.sharedManager()
var p = NEVPNProtocolIPSec()
manager.`protocol` = p

let pw = ""

p.username = ""
p.passwordReference = pw.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
p.serverAddress = ""
p.authenticationMethod = NEVPNIKEAuthenticationMethod.SharedSecret
//p.sharedSecretReference = getPasscodeNSData("vpnSharedSecret")
p.useExtendedAuthentication = true
p.disconnectOnSleep = false
```

Comment: Didn't use `NEVPNManager`, but from what I remember when I was configuring VPN networks, you should do this on the server side. In other words, when VPN connection is established, based on server side rules (VPN configuration), your local routing table is modified. You can set up it in a way that just some subnet will be routed through VPN, all traffic, ... Just my $.02, it's a long time ...

Comment: It looks like you're configuring a manager without starting it.  [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25027062/860000) appears to have a working example.

Comment: Did you see this? https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015-717/

Comment: Maybe my answer could help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/36124092/2858543

Answer (score 1):

From Apple:

> This is the default routing method. The IP routes are specified by the
>   Packet Tunnel Provider extension at the time that the VPN tunnel is
>   fully established. See NETunnelProvider for more details.

This is something the is specified from the Server end typically, l2tp does allow the user to toggle this setting. For that, take a look at `routingMethod` part of the [NETunnelProvider](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkExtension/Reference/NETunnelProviderClassRef/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NETunnelProvider/routingMethod). Scroll down to the `Routing Network Data to the VPN` section for the information you are looking for.